# add jquery datepicker event on newly added row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have the following javascript code in order to adding a new row on a table.
recently i added a jquery datepicker but the following code does not seem to work properly. how can i make it work?

```
function addLine(idTab,idRow,idForm,idContatore){

    var numLine=document.getElementById(idTab).rows.length-1;
    var tbody = document.getElementById
    (idTab).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    var oldLine=document.getElementById(idRow);
    var newLine=oldLine.cloneNode(true);
    numLine++;

    updateAttributes(newLine,'id',numLine);
    updateAttributes(newLine,'name',numLine);

    //resetValue(newRiga,'input');
    //resetValue(newRiga,'textarea');

    tbody.appendChild(newLine);
    tbody.appendChild(newLine);

    //attach datepicker
    $(".datepick").datepicker();

    document.getElementById(idContatore).value=numLine;

    //alert (numLine+' '+idContatore);

    //alert(document.getElementById(idContatore).value);
}

function updateAttributes(node,attr,newNum){
    if(node.hasChildNodes)
        for(var k=0,l=node.childNodes.length;k<l;k++)
            updateAttributes(node.childNodes[k],attr,newNum);

    if(node[attr]){
        var newAttrValue=node[attr].replace(/[0-9]+/,newNum);
        var IE=(document.all && !window.opera)?1:0;
        if(attr=='htmlFor'){
            node.removeAttribute(attr);
            attr=(IE)?'htmlFor':'for';
        }
        if(attr=='name' && node.type && node.type=='radio' && document.all && !window.opera)
            node.outerHTML=node.outerHTML.replace(/name=[^\s>]+/g, 'name='+newAttrValue);
        else node.setAttribute(attr,newAttrValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: `does not seem to work properly` isn't much of an explanation. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net and provide more details and any errors that are thrown

Comment: Where you are setting class 'datepick' to elements?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, *use* jQuery.

Comment: Please provide a demo on JSFiddle, there is no way to tell what is going on with the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding at the beginning of the addLine function che statement $(".datepick").datepicker("destroy"); .
I'm working on a better way of adding lines using jquery

Answer (score 0):

For all datepicker you can use this code. classname should be same

```
$('body').on('focus',".date-picker", function(){
$(this).datepicker();
});
```